# How can I include mariadb/conncpp.hpp in C++ Visual Studio 2019 on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mariadb

I am working on the project which is to get the data from CNC machine and store the data into the database. And the database that I use is MariaDB.

To connect the MariaDB to C++, I referred to the URL: https://mariadb.com/docs/clients/connector-cpp/#installing-mariadb-connector-c-via-msi-windows.

In this URL, it explains how to install MariaDB connector/C++ in Windows so I followed the instruction.

After that, when I input #include <mariadb/conncpp.hpp> on Visual Studio 2019, it says the system cannot open the file source mariadb/conncpp.hpp.

Could you explain how to solve this problem?

I believe the problem is that I skipped the section "Building C++ Application" which explains GNU GCC commands because I have no idea how I can do this on Windows but I am not sure.

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: Did you add the include path of the installed library to your project settings?

Comment: Yes I did and the application includes the header file correctly. Thank you.